# Is this a bug in React.cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs

[React's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) says:

> React.cloneElement() is almost equivalent to:
>
> `<element.type {...element.props} {...props}>{children}</element.type>`
>
> However, it also preserves refs. This means that if you get a child with a ref on it, you won't accidentally steal it from your ancestor. You will get the same ref attached to your new element.

So I made this small example:

```
import React, { Component, Children, cloneElement } from 'react';

class Wrapper extends Component {
    render() {
        return cloneElement(Children.only(this.props.children), {
            ref: (ref) => {
                console.log("wrapper", ref);
            },
        });
    }
}

const MyComponent = () =>
    <Wrapper>
        <div ref={ref => {
            console.log("original", ref);
        }}>
            My content
        </div>
    </Wrapper>

export default MyComponent;
```

(Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pxho45um/)

I thought rendering `MyComponent` would log both `"wrapper" <div>...</div>` and `"original" <div>...</div>`, but it seems like only the wrapper ref callback is called.

Isn't this contrary to the documentation? Or what do the React team mean when they say "if you get a child with a ref on it, you won't accidentally steal it from your ancestor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description is indeed very confusing, because child there doesn't refer to `[...children]` in `React.cloneElement(element, _, [...children])`, but to `element`.

> However, it (*it refers to React.cloneElement()*) also preserves refs. This means that if you get a child with a ref on it, you won't accidentally steal it from your ancestor. You will get the same ref attached to your new element.

So let's imagine the following scenario where in a component `<GrandParent />` you have

```
  <Parent ref='parent'>
    <Child ref='child'>
    </Child>
  <Parent />
```

Now GrandParent **assumes** that ref of `<Child />` is `'child'` and could potentially call `this.refs.child.doSomething()`.

However, in [previous version of react](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2984), if you clone the `<Child />` in `<Parent />`, `<GrandParent />` loses its ownership of `<Child />` and can no more call it by `this.refs`. This has been fixed as you see in the current version, so whenever you clone an element, its parent can still reference the clone.

---

Now I have an open question - what if you clone a `<Child />` twice in `<Parent />`, what happens to the reference in `<GrandParent />` - which of the clones does it refer to? I think the answer is [the last one](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/7ofevb4m/1/).

Comment: The complexity involved here is a good argument for avoiding refs and `cloneElement` altogether.